# javascript to display user defined element from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

i need to make simple javascript code to display an element from an array of fruits containing 5 elements but condition is that the fruit must be user defined that is index of fruit must be user supplied and javascript to print that.

text area must be user input and on submission it displays the element

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Please edit that (code) into your question, making it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could do this, perhaps the most simple is to use a prompt box.

```html
var fruits = ["fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3", "fruit4"];

var choice = prompt("Please enter a number between 0 and " + fruits.length);

// check that it is not null
if(choice)
{
  //convert to an integer
  parseInt(choice);
  alert(fruits[choice]);
  //or
  console.log(fruits[choice])
}
```

Obviously you should probably handle validation on the string to make sure that it is an integer!